# What is wrong with this simple calculator on Python3

Tags: python-3.x

This is the code,

```
while True :
    print(" your options are ")
    print(" enter add to add numbers ")
    print(" enter sub to subtract two numbers ")
    user_input = input("")

    if user_input == "quit":
      break
    elif user_input == "add":
        print ("you entered" +user_input )
        num1 = float (input ("enter a number"))
        num2 = float (input ("enter second number"))
        res = str ( num1 + num2 )
        print ( "result is" +res)
    elif user_input == "sub":
        print (user_input)
        num3 = float (input ("enter a number"))
        num4 = float (input ("enter second number"))
        res1 = str ( num3 + num4 )
        print ( "result is" +res4)
```

And input :

```
add
1
1
```

This is the output

```
your options are
enter add to add numbers
enter sub to subtract two numbers
you enteredadd
enter a number enter second number result
is2.0
your options are
enter add to add numbers
enter sub to subtract two numbers

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "..\Playground", line 5, in
<module>
user input = input("")
EOFError: EoF when reading a line
```

Yes,  the printable text had been repeated after having calculated the addition.

Comment: Are you using `while True :` on purpose ? Because this is why your code will be repeated again and again

Answer (score 0):

The calculator starts again after having printed the result of the operation because you do not `break` out of your while-loop.

Note that you also have an undefined name `ref4` on your last line. You probably meant `res1`.

#### Code

```
while True:
    print(" your options are ")
    print(" enter add to add numbers ")
    print(" enter sub to subtract two numbers ")
    user_input = input("")

    if user_input == "quit":
        break

    elif user_input == "add":
        print("you entered" + user_input)
        num1 = float(input("enter a number"))
        num2 = float(input("enter second number"))
        res = str(num1 + num2)
        print("result is" + res)
        break # This statement was added

    elif user_input == "sub":
        print(user_input)
        num3 = float(input("enter a number"))
        num4 = float(input("enter second number"))
        res1 = str(num3 + num4)
        print("result is" + res1) # 'res4' was replaced by 'res1'
        break # This statement was added
```

#### Output

```
 your options are 
 enter add to add numbers 
 enter sub to subtract two numbers 
add
you entered add
enter a number 1
enter second number 2
result is 3.0
```

## Improvements

Althought, let me suggest an improved and more scalable version using the `operator` module.

#### Code

```
import operator

operations = {
    'add': operator.add,
    'sub': operator.sub,
    'mul': operator.mul
}

while True:
    print('Your options are: ', 'quit', *operations)
    op = input('Enter an operation: ')
    if op == 'quit':
        break
    else:
        try:
            op = operations[op]
        except KeyError:
            print('Invalid opeartion')
            continue
    x = float(input('Enter a number: '))
    y = float(input('Enter a number: '))
    print('The result is:', op(x, y))
    break
```

#### Output

```
Your options are:  quit add sub mul
Enter an operation: mul
Enter a number: 2
Enter a number: 4
The result is: 8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I also think your codes have other bugs.
for example

```
res1 = str ( num3 + num4 )
print ( "result is" +res4)
```

It should fix that:

```
res1 = num3 - num4 
print ( "result is %f"%(res1))
```

Here is my codes:

```
while True :
    print(" your options are ")
    print(" enter add to add numbers ")
    print(" enter sub to subtract two numbers ")
    user_input = input("")

    if user_input == "quit":
      break
    elif user_input == "add":
        print ("you entered" +user_input )
        num1 = float (input ("enter a number"))
        num2 = float (input ("enter second number"))
        res = num1 + num2 
        print ( "result is %f" %(res))
        break
    elif user_input == "sub":
        print (user_input)
        num3 = float (input ("enter a number"))
        num4 = float (input ("enter second number"))
        res1 = num3 - num4 
        print ( "result is %f"%(res1))
        break
```

the output:

```
 your options are
 enter add to add numbers
 enter sub to subtract two numbers
sub
sub
enter a number-1.7
enter second number-8.7
result is 7.000000
```

If delete the `break`:

```
while True :
    print(" your options are ")
    print(" enter add to add numbers ")
    print(" enter sub to subtract two numbers ")
    user_input = input("")

    if user_input == "quit":
      break
    elif user_input == "add":
        print ("you entered" +user_input )
        num1 = float (input ("enter a number"))
        num2 = float (input ("enter second number"))
        res = num1 + num2 
        print ( "result is %f" %(res))
    elif user_input == "sub":
        print (user_input)
        num3 = float (input ("enter a number"))
        num4 = float (input ("enter second number"))
        res1 = num3 - num4 
        print ( "result is %f"%(res1))
```

the output:

```
your options are
 enter add to add numbers
 enter sub to subtract two numbers
add
you enteredadd
enter a number4
enter second number9
result is 13.000000
 your options are
 enter add to add numbers
 enter sub to subtract two numbers
sub
sub
enter a number4
enter second number5
result is -1.000000
 your options are
 enter add to add numbers
 enter sub to subtract two numbers
quit
```

the `while true` make the program run until you input `quit`.

Comment: Will anyone tell me, what purpose does that " while True: " serve?

Comment: Thank you so much guys. You've been really helpful

Comment: @NaveenKumar Because of the time difference, I reply so late. Your question tells me you do not like the printable text had been repeated. So the `break` I added lead to that `while True` dose not work. In fact, add the `while true`, you can continue to calculate until you input `quit`.If you have any question, please email me. If you like the answer, please accept and vote the answer. Thanks.

Comment: "So the break I added lead to that 'while True: 'dose not work"

Comment: What did you mean by that statement

Comment: And to be honest, i didn't get you